# Create a threadpool and create a exit signal in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I wanted to create a thread pool of 10 threads in Java and then keep them running executing the runnable and make them all running until none of the threads gets killed.

For managing that any of the thread got killed, I wanted to use handle exit signal in java. I am not sure how to do this implementation. So, can someone help how can I go about it.

Pseudo Code:

```
Atomic boolean shutdown = false;

handleExitSignal() {
    shutdown = true;
}

while(!shutdown) {
    runnable.run();
}
```

Not sure, how can I use the executor service, etc. in this? Any help you can provide would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Read this for how to use interrupts on Java threads: https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-stop

Simply interrupt the designated thread when you receive the stop signal That link shows how to do this with an atomic boolean like you already have in your pseudocode.